# Listar erros retornados em uma requisição ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, laravel

Tenho um Controller que está retornando erros dessa forma:

```
return response()->json(['erros' => $this->renderHttpException($e)]);
```

Estou recebendo esse json como resposta da requisição ajax:

```
{"email":["The email field is required."],"telefone":["The telefone field is required."]}
```

Preciso listar esses erros em uma div, sem ter que especificar cada campo como fiz com o email, como faço?

```
function Create(id, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: $('#' + id).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        error: function (data) {
            var errors = data.responseJSON;
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = errors.email;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Coloca a chamada do ajax.

Comment: coloquei a chamada ajax @rray

Comment: Quando laravel manda as msg de erro sempre da undefined? tentou trocar o `error:` por `done:` e nesse troco verificar se no objeto tem alguma mensagem?

Comment: É só `data.email` e `data.telefone`

Comment: Consegui pegando com isso: var errors = data.responseJSON; e colocando erros.email por exemplo. Mas agora como eu faço pra ele correr o json sem eu ter q especificar o campo? Porque são muitos, coloquei 2 aqui pra simplificar

Comment: Editei a pergunta para a situação atual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o **`each`** para percorrer o JSON

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: $('#' + id).serialize(),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
       $.each(data, function(i,v){
          $('#message').append('<span>'.v.'</span><br>');
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: Consegui dessa forma @Gumball, sugeri algumas edições pequenas para ficar da mesma forma que coloquei aqui, vlw!